# Stay Upright Within Rotating Area

Tags: godot, gdscript, godot-4

I am making a game that takes place in space and I want you to be able to stay upright in a spaceship even if it rotates. I have this set up:
[image]

Its a platform and an area that rotates. I have calculated a Vector based on the area's rotation that I use for the gravity and applied it to the cube and the player. It works somewhat but not well. When it rotates the cube slides off and hen the player is on it it doesn't go well. Basically I just take the rotation of the area and add it to the player and it works but not well. I need another way for approaching this.

My Player is a `CharacterBody3D` and the rotating ground is a `RigidBody3D`, but I am willing to change them.

Comment: Is the player a `RigidBody3D` or a `CharacterBody3D`? Do you need this to work for other objects "in the spaceship"? Also, is the ground a `StaticBody3D` or something else?

Comment: @Theraot Yes I need for other things to work in a "spaceship". The player is a `CharacterBody3D` and the platform is a `RigidBody3D`, but I am willing to change those if neccessary.

Comment: A bit of a hack you can try: instead of rotating the ship the player is on, you can rotate the world outside the ship around them, or rotate their *view* of the world through rendering transformations without even moving things "for real". This can often be much more stable in the physics engine, and avoid jitter/clipping or objects tunneling out of the ship because it "moved out from under them". Done right, it can be indistinguishable to the player — they used this trick in one of the Uncharted games when you're navigating a sinking sea vessel tossing on the waves, if I recall correctly.

Comment: Thank you for this advice and for providing an example. This really helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Direction of gravity

Since you might need `RigidBody3D` to change their direction of gravity… Have the `Area3D` override gravity (you can set its `gravity_space_override`, and set its `gravity_direction`). This direction is global, so you need to update it with the rotation of your `Area3D`:

*Code in the `Area3D`*

```
gravity_space_override = Area3D.SPACE_OVERRIDE_REPLACE
gravity_direction = global_transform.basis * Vector3.DOWN
```

---

Since you might need `CharacterBody3D` to follow the modified direction of gravity, have it read the gravity from the world space. For example:

*Code in the `CharacterBody3D`*

```
var direct_state := PhysicsServer3D.body_get_direct_state(get_rid())
var total_gravity := direct_state.total_gravity
```

However, you also need to tell the `CharacterBody3D` what is the new up which is used to identify what is a wall, a floor, or a ceiling:

```
up_direction = -total_gravity.normalized()
```

---

Then it gets tricky, because presumably you want the `CharacterBody3D` to rotate so it is standing up according to the new gravity direction.

I do not know how your code looks like, but you will have to review anywhere you have hardcoded `Vector3.UP`, and consider if it should be `up_direction` instead. For example, anywhere you are using `look_at`, you probably need to change it.

Character controllers often assume `Vector3.UP` is more implicit ways, for example mapping motion input to the horizonal axis, that code might need to be updated too.

---

### Moving inside the spaceship

Up to this point I have only talked about gravity. If the "spaceship" need to actually move it will bring more trouble.

First of all, having the `CharacterBody3D` is snapping to the floor will take care of situations of the floor moving away from it (at least at slow speeds).

The recommendation for a moving platform is an `AnimatableBody3D` and with `sync_to_physics` set to true. The `CharacterBody3D` when standing on the `AnimatableBody3D` moves with it.

**Thus: make the spaceship an `AnimatableBody3D`.**

But the `CharacterBody3D` won't change its orientation with whatever it is standing on. For that you need to detect the ground (e.g. use a `RayCast3D`), identify if it is the rotating platform, get how much it rotated last frame and rotate the `CharacterBody3D`.

I suggest you decompose the rotation in two parts:

- Rotation to align with the `up_direction` (make `global_transform.basis * Vector3.UP` go to `up_direction`). *Do this one first.*
- Rotation around the `up_direction` (the same way as the ground does).

*Be aware that the `CharacterBody3D` rotates around its own origin. If you want to have the origin in one place, but rotate around another ("center of mass") you need to handle do the translation that compensate for the difference after you rotated the `CharacterBody3D`.*

To do either of the mentioned rotations you want to get an axis and angle to have the `CharacterBody3D` rotate.

You might find it useful to use the `cross` product between vectors to use as axis. Be aware that `cross` product will be the zero vector if the inputs are either the same direction or opposite. You can use the `dot` product to discriminate which is the case.

It is also very useful to get an arbitrary perpendicular vector to another vector for these sort of things. This is what I'm currently using for that:

```
func get_perpendicular(direction:Vector3) -> Vector3:
    if direction.is_zero_approx():
        return Vector3.ZERO

    direction = direction.normalized()
    var vectors:= PackedVector3Array([Vector3.RIGHT, Vector3.UP, Vector3.BACK])
    for vec in vectors:
        var attempt = vec.slide(direction)
        if not attempt.is_equal_approx(Vector3.ZERO):
            return attempt.normalized()

    return Vector3.ONE.slide(direction).normalized()
```

This will return `Vector3.ZERO` if the `direction` given is zero. Otherwise it will try to get a perpendicular vector by taking the X, Y, Z axis vectors and substracting their projection on `direction`. Since there is no way the `direction` is perpendicular to all of them, one of them is bound to give you a valid perpendicular vector. *As a result the last line shouldn't run ever, but it is there so Godot does not complain that the method does not return, which is fine, since it does not handle pathological cases (i.e. `NAN` and `INF` coordinates), you should get an error trying to project on those.*

*You might also find this Q&A useful: [How to compare a vector to a rotation in Godot 4.1?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/207013/10408).*

---

### High speed

The above solution is bound to break a high speed. While you can try continuous collision detection on the `RigidBody3D`, the `CharacterBody3D` will always discrete collision detection.

Furthermore, at long distances you might run into floating point issues.

See [Moving player inside of moving spaceship?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/200945/10408).

*Thus DMGregory suggestion in comments is not unfounded.*

You can keep move everything so the "spaceship" is near the origin, by translating the root of the 3D world.

Yet, for rotating everything *except* your "spaceship", you want to set `top_level` on the "spaceship" so it is not affected by the transformation of the root of the 3D world (so you would also have to handle its offset translation). When you rotate the 3D world, since, presumably you want the rotation to happen around the "spaceship" you translate so the origin of the 3D world is on the "spaceship", rotate, and translate back.

---

And yes, it could also be done visually...

Doing it with materials is possible. But this is not as easy in Godot, since it imply making a transformation in the `vertex` shader *for everything* and *before* their regular material. So it can be quite an undertaking to set it up. At least, if you use Shader Global (you define them in project settings) you could control the transformation centrally.

Instead, I'd suggest to use a `SubViewport`s and `Camera3D`s trick: Have a `SubViewport` set to be rendered on top the regular world, and will have `own_world_3d` set to true. And inside of it you will have the "spaceship", and it will not move at all. To fake the motion, synchronize a `Camera3D` moving on the regular world with the local `Camera3D` of the "spaceship" scene plus the pretended motion of the "spaceship" itself.

Although this means that lights from the world won't affect the interior of the "spaceship", so you might want to replicate directional light and any other nearby lights that might affect it... And there will be edge cases (e.g. the light in the world would be inside the ship), but presumably you would have the "spaceship" fly at a safe distance from everything by design.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. I will try and implement this right now!